# mysql update a table from another table performance

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables,

table_A = 2500000+ (rows)
table_B = 6000000+ (rows)

I need to update rows in table_A from data in table_B (using a multithreaded application)

What is the fastest way

Option A

```
update table_b b (select col_a,col_b from table_a where col_c=%s) b set a.col_a=b.col_a, a.col_b=b.col_b flag='C' where col_c=%s
```

Option B

```
data=select col_a,col_bfrom table_a where col_c=%s
update table_b set col_a=%s,col_b=%s,flag='C' where col_c=%s
```

Option C

left join table_b with table_a

Comment: Don't use a left join unless you're looking to update entries in A that don't have a match in B.